# Conditional mean in python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, jupyter, mean

New to python. Looking to find a mean of 1 column if the 2nd column is below a specific number.
So let's say I have a data frame with 4 columns, 2 of which are age and salary. I would like to find out average salary for people below 40 and for people above 40.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question by editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mean_people_below_40 = df.loc[(df.age < 40)].salary.mean()
mean_people_above_40 = df.loc[(df.age > 40)].salary.mean()
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]**It calculates the mean of the ‘X’ column for every row in the DataFrame where the ‘Y’ column is equal to ‘The given Condition’.**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                 'full_marks': [99, 90, 93, 86, 88, 82],
                 'marks_obtained': [33, 28, 31, 39, 34, 30]}) print(df)

result = df.loc[df['class'] == 'A', 'marks_obtained'].mean() 
print("The mean is: ", result)
```

*Hope this helps*